# Retrieve values from a config file into a class, in C#?

Tags: c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Using C#. how would one get values from a config file into a class? I guess you can pass a key and it will get the value based on that.

I know you can use

```
string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"];
```

But I thought there might be a better way, maybe using it in a class?

Is this OK?

```
public static string GetKey(string value)
{
   get 
   {
      return ConfigurationSettingAppSetting[value];
   }
}
```

and to use it I use

```
GetKey("test");
```

Is this good or good pratice using it as a static?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer not to use strings to get values out of the configuration. Instead I create

```
public static class Config
{
    public static string Test
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Test"]; }
    }
}
```

also allowing for strong typing

```
public static class Config
{
    public static int ApplicationId
    {
        get { return int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationId"]); }
    }
}
```

This creates a simple abstraction without going all out and creating [configuration sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx).

Comment: Yuriy Faktorovich , what if I wanted to get more than 1 value? i.e. I want to control what gets passed over to the method. 

Like GetKey("test"); or GetKey("color");

Comment: @Greg generally I would create more static properties. Another possibility is having an enum which contains a list of keys. In most cases, I don't see why you'd need to dynamically pass in the keys.